# Kotlin Simplify Boolean Expression

Tags: kotlin, boolean-expression

Why do I get a minor error that says `"Simplify boolean expression"` in my `if` condition line?

For instance this snippet of code:

```
if (isClear==true){
    displayText.setText("")
}
```

Comment: It is not an error, it is a suggestion to improve your code. You can click on it an it will do it for you.

Comment: As @voddan said + it will work, but no one is doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following to simply the Boolean expression and avoid the error:

```
if (isClear) {
    displayText.setText("")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to add that in the case of warnings and errors in IDEA, you can invoke intention actions when your cursor is at them (`Alt + Enter` on Windows and Linux, `Command + Return` on Mac) to get possible fixes.

In your case, bringing up intention actions on the warning will look something like this:

[image: Intention actions: simplify boolean expression]

Choosing the single available option will do the transformation to the simplifed code for you:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the warning in the JetBrains IDEA: `File → Settings... → Editor → Inspections → Kotlin → Style issues → Boolean expression that can be simplified`

In fact there are cases when non-abbreviated code is more clear.
For example, I prefer `false == aVeryLongVariableOrFunctionName` to `!aVeryLongVariableOrFunctionName`, where the `!` is nearly invisible for the eyes.

Comment: Thank you! Because of my organization's coding standard, we explicitly show if statements as `if(someBoolean == true)` or `if(someBoolean == false)`, so being able to hide this warning was necessary.

Answer (score -5):

To handle Boolean isClear in Kotlin,following expression can be used.

```
when(isClear) {
 true -> {}
 false -> {}
}
```

However in case, isClear is nullable,we can use following code snippet.

```
 when(isClear) {
 true -> {}
 false -> {}
 null -> {}
}
```

Comment: If the `isClear` variable would be nullable, the compiler would complain. That is not the simplification we are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.